# How can I set a word as bold in a TextView with fontFamily open sans semi bold in Android?

Tags: android, html, textview, font-family

I need help to understand the following issue.

I need to set a single word of a TextView as bold.

I have a layout with a TextView with id `myTextView`:

```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/myTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semi_bold"
      android:textColor="#d94256"
      android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I set text to this view programmatically this way:

```
myTextView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml("My fancy string where I want to show this <b>word</b> bold", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Also, I tried to use spannable string builder but I got [the result of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzuKg.png) in both cases.

Why don't I get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NfFj.png)? I get this result when I change this line:

`android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semi_bold"`

for this one:

`android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_regular"`

And also, if I set

`android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"`

I can see [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ZhT.png)

I found the ttf files for [open_sans_semi_bold](https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/apache/opensans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf), [open_sans_bold](https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/apache/opensans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf) and [open_sans_regular](https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/apache/opensans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) in a google git repository.

Isn't Html `<b>` tag supposed to be as bold as OpenSans Bold?

Answer (score 0):

This is my string highlight function. Shows substring bold, in addition you can define different color for highlighted string if you want.

```
@Nullable
public static Spannable highlightString(@NonNull String s, @NonNull String subString, int color) {

    int startPos = s.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).indexOf(subString.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
    int endPos = startPos + subString.length();

    if (startPos != -1) {
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(s);
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{color});
        TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, colorStateList, null);
        try {
            spannable.setSpan(highlightSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return spannable;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
Spannable highlightedText = highlightString("My fancy string where I want to show this word bold", "word", Color.BLUE);
if (highlightedText != null)
    myTextView.setText(highlightedText);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I tried your code and work fine as long as TextView fontFamily is "less bold" than openSans semi bold. It's just the same issue that it's happening to me.

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @SergiLlamas did you try android:textStyle in your xml. Also I recommend https://fonts.google.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response but I think it wouldn't work because I need to set just a single word of a string as bold, not the full string. But is it possible to set textStyle semibold using xml? I mean, not using fontFamily

Comment: If you don't use fontFamily, default font will be used

Comment: Not working with a custom font that I use (avenir medium)